# Why can I access to blocked port while AWS Security Group allow to access to that port

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

I found an awkward thing about AWS Security Group.

I have two ec2 instances. Let's call them A and B.

A and B are in the same private subnet.

I opened port 3306 in instance A with the security group so any instance in the subnet can access it.

When I blocked the instance A's 3306 port with the command `sudo ufw deny 3306`, I found that the port is still accessible.

Why can I access the port that is blocked by ubuntu's firewall?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "I found that the port is still accessible"? How do you determine the port is accessible?

Comment: I accessed a MySQL server in instance A from instance B